# Not able to Navigate to another Activity when clicked on Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

When I click on a Notification I should be able to Navigate to second Activity but I am not able to navigate to second Activity(Main2Activity).

Please let me know what is the mistake,below is my code:

```
        public void onClick(View view) {

            NotificationCompat.Builder  noti = new 
            NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            noti.setContentTitle("Message for you!");
            noti.setContentText("Hi!!This is message for you");
            noti.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
            noti.setTicker("app name:message app");
            noti.setAutoCancel(true);
            Notification notification=noti.build();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(MainActivity.this);
            taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(Main2Activity.class);
            taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent= taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(1234,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            noti.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1234,notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Notification notification=noti.build();
```

above line was misplaced should be written after

`noti.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);`

once this is done above code will work fine.

Thanks